# python script to replace third byte of IP address

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python script which needs to run an operation by modifying an existing IP address.
it needs to replace the third byte of an IP address which is constant in all cases for me.
`x.x.16.x` to `x.x.17.x`

i can use a `str.replace('16','17')` if i know that there wont be any '16' in any other byte.

but i am trying to make it more generic. is there a simpler way to achieve this without using a lot of parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this

```
ips = ["x.16.x.x", "16.x.x.x"]

for ip in ips:
  p = ip.split(".")
  p[1] = "16"
  print(".".join(p))
```